# How do i use a pie chart in c# winform?

Tags: c#, winforms, charts

[image]

Why is my pie chart not working properly when i am trying to load the chart data according to the data i entered above?

the code below is how we get our input for data

```
List<clsData> datapointlst = new List<clsData>();
foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
{
    clsData data = new clsData();
    data.seriesName = dr[0].ToString();
    data.pointLabel = dr[1].ToString();
    data.toolTip = dr[2].ToString();
    data.x = int.Parse(dr[3].ToString());
    data.y = int.Parse(dr[4].ToString());
    datapointlst.Add(data);

    chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.LabelStyle.Format = dr[1].ToString();
}
```

This code is how i get my chart type

```
switch (type)
{
    case 0:
        return SeriesChartType.Point;
    case 1:
        return SeriesChartType.Line;
    case 2:
        return SeriesChartType.Bar;
    case 3:
        return SeriesChartType.Point;
    case 4:
        return SeriesChartType.StackedColumn;
    case 5:
        return SeriesChartType.Pie;
    default: 
        break;
}
```

Comment: What charting engine do you use and what exactly is not working? I see a singe data row and a pie chart reflecting that.

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12250747/how-can-i-add-a-pie-chart-to-my-winforms-application

Comment: A pie Chart splits the pie into as any parts as you have added DataPoints and their sizes reflect the yValues. With only one point the pie will consist of only one 'slice'.